# SMTP mail sending in c# with azure access token

Tags: c#, azure, smtp, access-token

I wanted to send a mail using SMTP server with Azure access token. 
I have an application hosted in azure and user login with tenant active directory. I found a code which does the same for google account [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-access-smtp-imap-server-using-oauth-inside).
Can someone help me?

I tried with the below code, generated azure access token and tried to send it to SMTP as below. But something is missing here and going in other way as this code is not sending mail.

```
public async Task SendmailusingOAuthToken()
{
    try
    {
        string accessToken = await new AppConfig().GetTokenForApplication();
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
        "Anita.Sure@mindtree.com",
        "Anita.Sure@mindtree.com",
        "NETWORKNET-33499 - " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        "Access to SMTP servers using OAuth");
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587))//, "user1@testaccount1913.narod2.ru", accessToken, true))
        {
            client.Timeout = 400000;
            //client.SecurityMode = SmtpSslSecurityMode.Implicit;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.SendAsync(message, accessToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Token generation code:

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
{
    try
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's token filecache
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new FileCache(signedInUserID));
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred,
        new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have found the code and what have you tried so far with that, any errors?

Comment: So please post the code and the exact error you are facing

Comment: @IpsitGaur I have edited my question with the code